# Copying folders and files using wildcards

Tags: bash

I have a shell script that backs up and restores the calibration of a scanner device.

**Code:**

```
if [ "-backup" == "$1" ]; then
  if [ ! -d $BACKUPDIR ]; then
    mkdir -p $BACKUPDIR
    cp -r -d $HOME/Syscan_DocketPORT465 $BACKUPDIR/Syscan_DocketPORT465
    cp -r -d $HOME/DocuCap_DocketPORT467 $BACKUPDIR/DocuCap_DocketPORT467
  fi
elif [ "-restore" == "$1" ]; then
  if [ -d $BACKUPDIR ]; then
    cp $BACKUPDIR/Syscan_DocketPORT465/* $HOME/Syscan_DocketPORT465/
    cp $BACKUPDIR/DocuCap_DocketPORT467/* $HOME/DocuCap_DocketPORT467/
  fi
fi
```

Right now, it backs up 2 folders, `Syscan_DocketPORT465` and `DocuCap_DocketPORT467`. In these folders is a file called `Calibration.dat`.

What I need to do now, is make it so that every folder that follows `*_DocketPORT*` to be backed up and restored so that every time a new configuration for a DocketPORT is added, we don't need to edit the script.

**I have tried this:**

```
if [ "-backup" == "$1" ]; then
  if [ ! -d $BACKUPDIR ]; then
    mkdir -p $BACKUPDIR
    cp -r -d $HOME/*_DocketPORT* $BACKUPDIR
  fi
elif [ "-restore" == "$1" ]; then
  if [ -d $BACKUPDIR ]; then
    cp -r -d $BACKUPDIR/*_DocketPORT/* $HOME
  fi
fi
```

For backup, this works fine!

But for restore it keeps telling me that it can't overwrite the previously created `/home/path/Calibrate.dat` with `/home/path/Syscan_DocketPORT465/Calibration.dat`

So basically, it keeps putting `Calibration.dat` in `/home/path/` instead of in `/home/path/SOMEDOCUCAPFOLDER/` for some reason.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second `cp` command has an incorrect slash in `*_DocketPORT/*`. It should be `*_DocketPORT*`. Try changing it to:

```
cp -r -d $BACKUPDIR/*_DocketPORT* $HOME
```

Comment: You da man dawg. I can't believe I didn't see that myself :) I guess sometimes you just need a second pair of eyes.